# Alexa Skill Testing on Echo Dot

Tags: java, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have created a Java custom Lambda skill for the amazon echo dot.

The skill is enabled and hosed in N.Virginia (arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1....).

- Skill (Green Tick)
- Information  (Green Tick)
- Interaction  Model (Green Tick)
- Configuration  (Green Tick)
- Test (Green Tick)
- Publishing Information (grey)
- Privacy & Compliance (grey)

Under the developer console for testing the skill when inputting written text everything is working with no issues. The skill has not been published.

I wish to test the skill with my Echo Dot which is registered to the developer account. I can see the skill listed in the You Apps list in the Alexa App.

The issue I am having is that when I ask the Echo Dot to launch it it can never find the skill I just created.

Any ideas ?

The invocation name is: building god

I don't wish to publish the skill to the whole world as I am currently still learning but I would like to test it with the Echo Dot as opposed to the browser only typing mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that you need to have your Amazon Echo Dot set to US English for it to work.

Or preferably, configure your skill for English (UK) as well as English (US)

Comment: Alternatively, configure your skill for English (UK) as well as English (US)